Add two affiliations to an author name
I would like to assign two ranges to an author. Something like this: $\text{name}^{b,c}$
This is my code so far. Unfortunately, the second is always overwritten by the third. How can I prevent this?
\author[first]{NameA}
\affiliation[first]{organization={Faculty of Business and Economics; University},
country={Germany}}
\author[first]{NameB}
\author[third]{NameC}
\affiliation[third]{organization={Department of Technology},country={Germany}} 
\affiliation[third]{organization={Second Department; Another University},country={Another Country}}


Does this answer your question? Multiple Authors with common affiliations in IEEEtran conference template
